# Interact with angular directive via button placed anywhere

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive somewhere on my page. I assign the id attribute to that directive. It doesn't matter what the directive actually does.

The key point is that I now want a second directive that basically activates the first directive.

So something like this:

```
<body>
    <!-- bunch of elements -->
    <my-directive id="test"></my-directive>
    <!-- bunch of elements -->
    <controlling-directive directive-id="test"></controlling-directive>
</body>
```

The `controllingDirective` would be defined like so:

```
.directive('controllingDirective', function() {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function(){
            // call directive with attrs.directiveId
        });
    }
}
```

The question is: how do I actually achieve this and what is the best way?

I thought of two things:

By using document.getElementById and angular.element(..).isolateScope() like so:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.actionToStart = function() {...};
    }
}


.directive('controllingDirective', function() {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function(){
            angular.element(document.getElementById(attrs.directiveId))
                    .isolateScope().actionToStart();
        });
    }
}
```

Or by using a event on $rootScope:

```
.directive('myDirective', function($rootScope) {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        $rootScope.$on(attrs.id + 'Start', function(){...});
    }
}


.directive('controllingDirective', function($rootScope) {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function(){
            $rootScope.$emit(attrs.directiveId + 'Start');
        });
    }
}
```

I somehow don't like both possiblities. Is there a simple thing I'm missing, how something like this is supposed to be done?

Note that I can't use the 'require'-option, since the directives are not related in the DOM.

Comment: What do you mean 'activate' and 'call directive'?  You can't call a directive, it's a DOM element.  What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: if your directives are not related in the DOM, then possibly you need use services instead

Comment: It really doesn't matter, in this case it is just a simple panel that should be shown or not shown, but I can use this somewhere else as well. The point is that I just want a button or something that can control the directive from any place in the dom.

Comment: @TimoTürschmann, in most cases in angular you not need work with dom directly, and for you sample with _panel that should be shown or not shown_ enough simple set flag that passed in directive by attribute, or by services. Can you provide more specific problem what you try solve? possibly you need simple [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: The two elements do not live in the same controller. Passing a attribute thus would not work.

Comment: @TimoTürschmann just use services - it not depend from controller

Comment: @TimoTürschmann if you provide working code snippet or plunker, i can change it and possibly can help solve your problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x5b4xtva/ my problem is not that it's not working, my problem is that I think this is hacky and I thought maybe there is an idiomatic way on how to "talk" to a directive outside of controller/DOM bounds...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77931/discussion-between-grundy-and-timo-turschmann).

Answer (score 0):

Methinks you not need use *angular.element* or even events, just simple watch and attributes

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '{{cur}}',
    scope: {
      cur: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      if (!scope.cur) scope.cur = 1;
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return scope.cur;
      }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
          if (oldVal == 4) scope.cur = 1;
        }
      });
    }
  };
}).directive('controllingDirective', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    scope: {
      directiveCur: '='
    },
    template: '<button type="button" ng-click="click()">Click me</button>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.click = function() {
        scope.directiveCur += 1;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div>
    <my-directive data-cur="test"></my-directive>
    <controlling-directive directive-cur="test"></controlling-directive>
  </div>
  <div>
    <my-directive data-cur="test2"></my-directive>
    <controlling-directive data-directive-cur="test2"></controlling-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** variant with *$rootScope*

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('Test', function($scope) {});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    template: '{{test}}',
    scope: {
      cur: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      if (!$rootScope[scope.cur]) scope.test = $rootScope[scope.cur] = 1;
      console.log($rootScope[scope.cur], scope.test);
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return $rootScope[scope.cur];
      }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
          if (oldVal == 4) scope.test = $rootScope[scope.cur] = 1;
          else scope.test = $rootScope[scope.cur];
        }
      });
    }
  };
});


myApp.directive('controllingDirective', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    scope: {
      directiveCur: '@'
    },
    template: '<button type="button" ng-click="click()">Click me</button>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.click = function() {
        $rootScope[scope.directiveCur] += 1;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <my-directive data-cur="test"></my-directive>
  <controlling-directive directive-cur="test"></controlling-directive>
  <br/>
  <my-directive data-cur="test2"></my-directive>
  <span ng-controller="Test">
    <controlling-directive data-directive-cur="test2"></controlling-directive>
  </span>
  <div>test: {{test}}
    <br/>test2: {{test2}}</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE2** variant with factory

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('shared', function() {
  return {
    inc: function(cur) {
      if (this[cur] == 4) this[cur] = 1;
      else this[cur] += 1;
    }
  }
});
myApp.controller('Test', function($scope) {});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function(shared) {
  return {
    template: '{{shared[cur]}}',
    scope: {
      cur: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      if (!shared[scope.cur]) shared[scope.cur] = 1;
      scope.shared = shared;
    }
  };
});


myApp.directive('controllingDirective', function(shared) {
  return {
    scope: {
      directiveCur: '@'
    },
    template: '<button type="button" ng-click="click()">Click me</button>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.click = function() {
        shared.inc(scope.directiveCur);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <my-directive data-cur="test"></my-directive>
  <controlling-directive directive-cur="test"></controlling-directive>
  <br/>
  <my-directive data-cur="test2"></my-directive>
  <span ng-controller="Test">
    <controlling-directive data-directive-cur="test2"></controlling-directive>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the directives won't always be in the same scope, thus this will not work all the time.

Comment: @TimoTürschmann, _$rootScope_ is global, so all directives inside. If you provide sample with different scope, i update my answer

Comment: @TimoTürschmann, update answer: add variant with rootScope, and with factory